# Does the precision of datetime field change when used with bigint field to form a composite key or Unique Index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, composite-primary-key

I need to use a composite key or unique index comprised of a bigint data type and a datetime data type.  However, I've noticed that the seconds element of the datetime has been rounded to the nearest minute and causes a duplicate key violation when trying to import a dataset.

The dataset is essentially transactional data, so our ID (stored in the bigint field) will be repeated, hence the need for inclusion of the datetime field in the unique key.

To give an example: the following two rows cause a 'duplicate key row' error:

ID field (bigint)      |   ActionDate (datetime)
---------------------  |--------------------------
1050000284002       |   2016-01-08 15:51:24.000
1050000284002       |   2016-01-08 15:50:35.000

The values are clearly different (and are stored correctly in the database) but the error shows:

```
The duplicate key value is (1050000284002, Jan  8 2016  3:51PM).
```

(It's worth adding that I initially created a composite key and have since replaced it with a unique index; the error outlined above was generated with the index in place.)

My questions are:

1. Is my datetime field being rounded because I'm using an integer in the key/index?
2. Is there another reason that I lose the accuracy of the time component of the datetime field?
3. How can I rectify the issue so that the example wouldn't result in a key violation?

Comment: That's your input screwing you. Datetime format definition is clearly spelled in BOL. If you need higher precision, use Datetime2.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, ajeh.  I don't know what BOL is.  Given my edit (which includes the examples) are you still of the opinion that my datatype is wrong?

Comment: Before you do any further SQL development, you should familiarize yourself with the Books Online, or BOL.

Comment: Thank you for your rather patronising comment, ajeh.  However, I don't believe that the online definitions I have read to date help me with this particular problem (I'd appreciate any links to BOL you think will help resolve my particular issue).  While you will have astutely noticed that I am no SQL guru, I would appreciate it if you could better utilise your experience in a more constructive manner, rather than belittling people trying to use the forum in seeking help.

Comment: Hitting Shift-F1 while `datetime` is highlighted in SSMS should take you right there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an index of the form (index on columns A,B) and not a formulaic one (index on columns A + B), then no, the datatype of one column will have no effect on the contents of the other.

Based on your description, I'd check the following:

- The actual datatype of the datetime column. Is it datetime? (Datetime will round to the nearest 333rd of a second, though that's not the issue here.)
- The actual definition of the index. Is defined as you think it is defined? Perhaps it is indexing on date(DateTimeColumn)?
- The actual data being stored. Is whatever is loading the data into the table perhaps truncating the seconds?

---

Further suggestions based on your edit:

If the data you are importing clearly contains unique datetime values, yet SQL is not identifying unique date values, then something's up with the data import process.

Try this loading your data into the table **without** the index in place. Does it load? Does it match your source data to the millisecond? Now, with the data loaded, create the index (primary key, unique constraint, whatever). Does this fail? Where's the duplicate data coming from? In short, mess around with the data and loading processes and see what falls out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Phillip.  I've edited my question to provide more detail.  I don't believe my data is the issue.  I will have a closer look at my index.

Comment: Added to my answer

Comment: Thank you for your additional comments.  I believe the import process is creating a duplicate row somewhere (I'm using some joins to multiple other tables, so I think it's my import process).

Answer (score 0):

When I do this:

```
declare @i bigint
set @i=25
select   @i+getdate() 
select cast ( @i+getdate() as int)
```

I get:
2016-10-17 09:47:05.753

```
42658
```

Notice the first result is the date plus 25 days. So there is not dropoff in the integer part of the date (otherwise it would be midnight on the date...).

The second select drops everything after the decimal place....